# How to cancel Contacts.SearchAsync before finish the search in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, contacts, cancellation

I'm using Contacts.SearchAsync to get all user's contacts, in an WP8 app.
But i realized that, when the user has many contacts (like 1000+), this search takes a long time...

So, I was thinking in add an button, so the user has the option to cancel this search...

But I couldn't find any method that cancels this search...

Is there a way to cancel it, before it finishes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did not use this, but there is workaround.

If thread is terminated, all of its children-threads are terminated too.

Therefore if you run this method in new thread, you can always terminate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way to cancel the search but an alternative approach is to just ignore the completion of the search.

```
void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
   if (!searchWasCancelled)
   {
       // Process the search results
   }
}
```

Comment: but doesn't the _Contacts_SearchCompleted_ runs only after the contacts search finishes?

Comment: Yes, but the Contacts.SearchAsync method runs asynchronously (i.e. in the background) so your app can continue acting as if the search never happened. You can even start a second search (eg. if you wanted to provide additional criteria) and only process the results of your second search!